# Dynamic start_urls value

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and python.  I have written a spider that works fine with the initialized start_urls value.

It also works fine if I put a literal in the code in the Init as

{ self.start_urls = 'http://something.com' }

But, when I read the value in from a json file and create a list, I get the same error about a missing%20

I feel like I am missing something obvious in either scrapy or python because I am a nube.

```
class SiteFeedConstructor(CrawlSpider, FeedConstructor):

    name = "Data_Feed"
    start_urls = ['http://www.cnn.com/']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    FeedConstructor.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    kwargs = {}
    super(SiteFeedConstructor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.name = str(self.config_json.get('name', 'Missing value'))
    self.start_urls = str(self.config_json.get('start_urls', 'Missing value'))
    self.start_urls = self.start_urls.split(",")
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
    execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 132, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 97, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 139, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/runspider.py", line 64, in run
    self.crawler.crawl(spider)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 42, in crawl
    requests = spider.start_requests()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spider.py", line 55, in start_requests
    reqs.extend(arg_to_iter(self.make_requests_from_url(url)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spider.py", line 59, in make_requests_from_url
    return Request(url, dont_filter=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 26, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 61, in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: Missing%20value
```

Comment: Traceback error :
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 61, in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: Missing%20value

Comment: Please show how do you read the values from a json file.

Comment: The file is read in with:             js = None
    with open(filename) as fp:
        js = json.load(fp)
    assert js

Comment: It is set to a class attribute called config_json and then the individual fields are loaded from this variable.

Comment: def __init__(self, **config_json):

 """
 Extract the json and initialize the common feed properties
 """
 self.config_json = config_json
 self.title = str(self.config_json.get('title', 'Missing value'))
        self.storage_file = str(self.config_json.get('storage_file', 'Missing value'))
        self.log_file = str(self.config_json.get('log_file', 'Missing value'))

Comment: it seems that you haven't assigned any value on `self.start_urls` in `__init__` function

Comment: @user3746535 , please edit your question to add those code snippets from your comments. The formatting will be much better

Comment: Added code to the question!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining `__init__()` override [`start_requests()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_requests) method:

> This is the method called by Scrapy when the spider is opened for
>   scraping when no particular URLs are specified. If particular URLs are
>   specified, the make_requests_from_url() is used instead to create the
>   Requests. This method is also called only once from Scrapy, so it’s
>   safe to implement it as a generator.

```
class SiteFeedConstructor(CrawlSpider, FeedConstructor):
    name = "Data_Feed"

    def start_requests(self):
        self.name = str(self.config_json.get('name', 'Missing value'))
        for url in str(self.config_json.get('start_urls', 'Missing value')).split(","):
            yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)
```

Comment: That eliminates the errors, but I don't get any output from the spider.

Comment: @user3746535 ok, what is the current output? Thanks.

Comment: if I run the spider with the "hard coded" cnn.com assigned to the attribute, I get a whole list of links in the output CSV file:

Comment: website,url,name,title

http://www.cnn.com/,http://www.cnn.com/,Missing value,Missing value

http://www.cnn.com/,http://www.cnn.com/OPINION/?hpt=sitenav,Missing value,Missing value

http://www.cnn.com/,http://ireport.cnn.com/?hpt=sitenav,Missing value,Missing value

http://www.cnn.com/,http://www.cnn.com/2014/06/17/health/senate-grills-dr-oz/index.html?hpt=hp_inthenews,Missing value,Missing value

http://www.cnn.com/,http://www.cnn.com/2014/06/17/us/ohio-mummified-body/index.html?hpt=hp_inthenews,Missing value,Missing value

....etc, etc....

Comment: If I use the suggested override, the output CSV file is blank.

Comment: @user3746535 ok, thanks for the info. Could you put `print url` inside the `for` loop in `start_requests()` and see what is printed on the console? Need to make sure what is yielded. Thanks.

Comment: When I add print url, i still get nothing and nothing is printed to the screen.

Comment: def start_requests(self):
        self.name = str(self.config_json.get('name', 'Missing value'))
        for url in str(self.config_json.get('start_urls', 'Missing value')).split(","):
            yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)

Comment: @user3746535 ok, this is already something. Could you print the value of `str(self.config_json.get('start_urls', 'Missing value'))` before the loop? Thanks.

Comment: user@ubuntuvm:/data_feed$ python feed_initializer.py -d conf/feed_def_website.json
['http://www.msn.com/']   ***<<<this is the output from the var>>>
Constructing feed <WebsiteFeedConstructor 'Web Name' at 0xb5432f4c>
Constructing feed <WebsiteFeedConstructor 'Web Name' at 0xb5432f4c>

Comment: user@ubuntuvm:/data_feed$ python feed_initializer.py -d conf/feed_def_website.json (this is the call that starts the spider)
http://www.msn.com/ (this is the value from the json)
http://www.msn.com/ (this is the value applying hte str function)
['http://www.cnn.com/'] (this is with the split function)
Constructing feed <WebsiteFeedConstructor 'Website Feed' at 0xb568b34c>
Constructing feed <WebsiteFeedConstructor 'Website Feed' at 0xb568b34c>